# Greens Third Identity Proof/Derivation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Does anyone know how to derive Green's third identity? I would appreciate your help a lot. Thank you

Argument is here:

$$ \int_D \nabla u . \nabla v= \oint_{\partial D} v \partial_n u - \int_D v \Delta u$$

Answer (score 0):

To fill in the missing steps, we can use the vector calculus identity:
$$ \nabla . (v \nabla u)= \nabla v . \nabla u + v \nabla^2 u.$$
Then we can integrate both sides over the domain $D$, replacing the left-hand side with line integral along the boundary surface $\partial D$ using Stoke's theorem:
$$ \oint_{\partial D} v \nabla u.d \mathbf S = \int_D \nabla v . \nabla u\ dV +  \int_D v  \nabla^2u \ dV$$

---

**Edit:** (to respond to comment)

By reversing the roles of $u$ and $v$, one can derive a similar equation. Subtrating the two equations, one finds that
$$ \oint_{\partial D} (v \nabla u - u \nabla v).d \mathbf S = \int_D (v  \nabla^2u - u \nabla^2 v) \ dV \ \ \ \ (\ast) $$

One typical application of this form of Green's theorem is when we are trying to solve the PDE:
$$ \nabla^2 u(\mathbf x) = f(\vec x) {\rm \ \ in \ \ } D, \ \ \ \ u(\mathbf x) = g(\vec x) {\rm \ \ on \ \ } \partial D.$$
One does this by finding a Green's function $G$ satisfying
$$ \nabla^2 G(\mathbf x, \mathbf x') = \delta^3(\mathbf x - \mathbf x') {\rm \ \ in \ \ } D , \ \ \ \ G(\mathbf x, \mathbf x') = 0 {\rm \ \ on \ \ } \partial D. $$

By substituting $v(\mathbf x) = G(\mathbf x, \mathbf x')$ into $(\ast)$, we get:
$$ 0 - \oint_{\partial D} g(\mathbf x) \nabla_{\mathbf x} G(\mathbf x, \mathbf x')  .d \mathbf S_{\mathbf x} = \int_D G(\mathbf x, \mathbf x' )  f(\mathbf x)  \ dV_{\mathbf x} - u(\mathbf x') ,$$
which can be rearranged to give the solution to the PDE:
$$ u(\mathbf x') = \int_D G(\mathbf x, \mathbf x' )  f(\mathbf x)  \ dV_{\mathbf x} + \oint_{\partial D} g(\mathbf x) \nabla_{\mathbf x} G(\mathbf x, \mathbf x')  .d \mathbf S_{\mathbf x} $$

Comment: I see it better now, so the second integral can be eliminated if v is chosen to be green's function if I am not mistaken and that would be the end of the proof right?

Comment: @JorgeFloresOrtega It's slightly more complicated than that. I edited the answer.

Comment: I see it now, thanks a lot!!!